# Problem with formatting and displaying outputs with tkinter and loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to have my program format properly in a tkinter GUI but for some reason I get the error message:

```
    product += ('%-10s%-10s%-0s%-0s') % (str(names[i])+ str(addedHours[i]) + str(payOut) + "\n") TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Desired Output:
[image]

Here is the snip of code related to the problem (Note that the Name/Hours/Pay and --- parts are working fine, just not the ones under the variable product)

```
    def printPayroll(self):

        i = 0
        product = ""
        for y in names:

            payOut = float(wage[i]) * float(addedHours[i])
            product += ('%-10s%-10s%-0s%-0s') % (str(names[i])+ str(addedHours[i]) + str(payOut) + "\n")

            i += 1

        self.text.insert(END,("%-10s%-10s%-0s") % ('Name', 'Hours', 'Pay\n'))
        self.text.insert(END,("%-10s%-10s%-0s") % ('---','-----','---\n'))

        self.text.insert(END, product)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get, `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`, is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Consider this line of code:

```
product += ('%-10s%-10s%-0s%-0s') % (str(names[i])+ str(addedHours[i]) + str(payOut) + "\n")
```

The above code is functionally identical to this:

```
s = str(names[i]) + str(addedHours[i]) + str(payOut) + "\n"
product += ('%-10s%-10s%-0s%-0s') % s
```

Your formatting string requires four arguments but you are only giving one. The simple solution is to replace every `+` with a `,`:

```
product += ('%-10s%-10s%-0s%-0s') % (str(names[i]), str(addedHours[i]),  str(payOut), "\n")
```

Comment: what a god <3 <3 <3

Comment: @jimmyjohn123: no, not really. You just need to read the error message and assume it's telling you the truth. Then, ask yourself "why does it think I'm only providing one argument?".

Comment: also, if I were to insert a dollar sign in the str(payOut) what would I need to do?

Comment: yeah that is true, I assumed using '+' separates then into different arguments like how ',' does it.

Comment: @jimmyjohn123: if you want a dollar sign in the output, you would put it in the format string.